# Text wont output on screen C++ / OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, character

I am currently trying to output a string onto screen in OpenGL my relevant code is as follows:

```
void drawBitmapText(char *string,float x,float y) 
{  
    char *c;
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);

    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, *c);
    }
}
```

Where my display function looks like so:

```
void display(void)
{
   int speed=frame/20;

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   frame++;
   if((frame>=0) && (frame<1000))   // Scene 1.
   {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    drawBitmapText("Hello World",200,200);
    glutSwapBuffers(); 
   }
}
```

I believe I have implemented it correctly but apparently not. Any ideas?

Comment: Change to `*c != '\0'` or `*c != 0`

Comment: Ill try that but I have no need for the z axis. I'll get it a go :)

Comment: What's your projection transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure can you re word that I am new to opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the xy position passed to `glRasterPos2f(x, y);` lies outside the viewport after transformation, the following raster drawing operations will be omitted until a new raster position that transforms to within the viewport is specified.

If you don't know what "transformation" and "viewport" mean you should educate yourself on this. Only so much: The coordinates given to `glRasterPos` are not pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The position passed to `glRasterPos2f()` is processed just like vertices you pass to draw calls. This means that the current transformations (modelview and projection) are applied to the position.

If you don't specify any transformations, the default for both of these is the identity transformation. This means that the resulting coordinates are the same as the input coordinates.

Once all transformations are applied, OpenGL expects that the resulting coordinates are in a coordinate system called Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC). In this coordinate system, the range [-1.0, 1.0] for each coordinate direction maps to the window size. Which means that if no transformations are applied, your input coordinates should already be within that range.

I can think of at least 3 options to get this working for you:

- Specify coordinates in the range [-1.0, 1.0]. For example:

  ```
  glRasterPos2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
  ```

  would place text at the bottom left corner, and:

  ```
  glRasterPos2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
  ```

  places it at the center of the window.
- If you want to specify the position in pixels, set up a corresponding projection transformation:

  ```
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIndentity();
  glOrtho(0.0, width, 0.0, height, -1.0, 1.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  ```
- Use `glWindowPos2f()` instead of `glRasterPos2f()`. This function also sets the raster position, but takes input in window coordinates (which are in pixel units), and does not apply the current transformations.